# Does android Firebase RTDB parsing use property names or appropriate accessor methods?

Tags: android, firebase-realtime-database

Consider the following `VersionClass`. Assume that the FRTDB has a node matching this model.

When the firebase android library tries to serialize or deserialize the class (`getValue(VersionClass.class)` *or* `setValue(new VersionClass())`):

1. Will it only use the accessor methods *(e.g. `getVersionCode(), setVersionCode(int versionCode)`)*?
    Or search for exact property names in my class *(e.g. `versionCode`)*?
2. If I keep the accessor method names unchanged, and change the variable names, *(e.g. `versionCode` to `anotherNameForVersion`, but `getVersionCode(), setVersionCode(int versionCode)` names are untouched)* will the code fail?

[image: Database Node]

```
public class VersionClass {
    private int versionCode;
    private String versionName;
    private int osCode;
    private String osName;
    private String deviceName;
    private String model;
    private String manufacturer;

    public VersionClass() {

    }

    public VersionClass(int versionCode, String versionName, int osCode, String osName, String deviceName, String model, String manufacturer) {
        this.versionCode = versionCode;
        this.versionName = versionName;
        this.osCode = osCode;
        this.osName = osName;
        this.deviceName = deviceName;
        this.model = model;
        this.manufacturer = manufacturer;
    }

    public int getVersionCode() {
        return versionCode;
    }

    public void setVersionCode(int versionCode) {
        this.versionCode = versionCode;
    }

    public String getVersionName() {
        return versionName;
    }

    public void setVersionName(String versionName) {
        this.versionName = versionName;
    }

    public int getOsCode() {
        return osCode;
    }

    public void setOsCode(int osCode) {
        this.osCode = osCode;
    }

    public String getOsName() {
        return osName;
    }

    public void setOsName(String osName) {
        this.osName = osName;
    }

    public String getDeviceName() {
        return deviceName;
    }

    public void setDeviceName(String deviceName) {
        this.deviceName = deviceName;
    }

    public String getModel() {
        return model;
    }

    public void setModel(String model) {
        this.model = model;
    }

    public String getManufacturer() {
        return manufacturer;
    }

    public void setManufacturer(String manufacturer) {
        this.manufacturer = manufacturer;
    }
}
```

**Edited Copy:**

```
public class VersionClass {
    private int newVersionCode;
    private String versionName;
    private int osCode;
    private String osName;
    private String deviceName;
    private String model;
    private String manufacturer;

    public VersionClass() {

    }

    public VersionClass(int newVersionCode, String versionName, int osCode, String osName, String deviceName, String model, String manufacturer) {
        this.newVersionCode = newVersionCode;
        this.versionName = versionName;
        this.osCode = osCode;
        this.osName = osName;
        this.deviceName = deviceName;
        this.model = model;
        this.manufacturer = manufacturer;
    }

    public int getVersionCode() {
        return newVersionCode;
    }

    public void setVersionCode(int versionCode) {
        this.newVersionCode = versionCode;
    }

    public String getVersionName() {
        return versionName;
    }

    public void setVersionName(String versionName) {
        this.versionName = versionName;
    }

    public int getOsCode() {
        return osCode;
    }

    public void setOsCode(int osCode) {
        this.osCode = osCode;
    }

    public String getOsName() {
        return osName;
    }

    public void setOsName(String osName) {
        this.osName = osName;
    }

    public String getDeviceName() {
        return deviceName;
    }

    public void setDeviceName(String deviceName) {
        this.deviceName = deviceName;
    }

    public String getModel() {
        return model;
    }

    public void setModel(String model) {
        this.model = model;
    }

    public String getManufacturer() {
        return manufacturer;
    }

    public void setManufacturer(String manufacturer) {
        this.manufacturer = manufacturer;
    }
}
```

Data from an affected node:
[image: Data From Affected Node]

It appears while setting, firebase is searching fields directly through reflection, I may need to do my work first, then populate target fields exactly before calling `setValue()`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Will it only use the accessor methods (e.g. getVersionCode(), setVersionCode(int versionCode))? Or search for exact property names in my class (e.g. versionCode)?

It can use eithe rone.  But you might have to make the property public if you want to use that instead of the setter.  This should be easy enough for you to try for yourself.

> If I keep the accessor method names unchanged, and change the variable names, (e.g. versionCode to anotherNameForVersion, but getVersionCode(), setVersionCode(int versionCode) names are untouched) will the code fail?

No, it will not fail.  It will use the getter methods that match, according to the JavaBeans spec.  This also should be easy for you to test for yourself by simply making the change, recompiling your app, and running it.

If you need to map a child value to a java bean, and the names, don't match, you can use the [@PropertyName](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/database/PropertyName) annotation to help it match properties or getters.

Comment: In my case, the entry will be a setter(which will match the key in the node). I want to keep my variables independent of the accessor because a bit of pre-processing is required in my app. I'd like the association to end at the accessor method, after that I don't want firebase to meddle with whatever goes on under the hood.

Comment: Sure, give it a try.

Comment: OK, your questions stayed the same, and my answers stayed the same.  If there is something that isn't working the way you expect, please ask a new question and explain the behavior that's not consistent.  Seems like both of your original questions could simply be answered by some experimentation on your part.

Comment: Yes, I'm marking this answered, added the last edit to note the setter behavior